# Is there room in overhead bins on CRJ900 for a roll-aboard?

Tags: hand-luggage

I have a 46-minute connection at LGA so I really don't want to wait on the jet bridge for my bag. Can the CRJ900 accommodate a normal-size carry-on in the overhead bins or do I need to bring my tiny one?

Comment: What I see these days on planes is that even if the overhead bins can hold normal size carry-on's, there are so many that quite a few people have to gate check their luggage. It might be best to take the tiny one if you can fit enough in.

Comment: Which airline is this on? The CRJ "NextGen" bins are very slightly larger than the older bins, and I believe planes delivered after 2016 had another very slight increase.

Comment: I think there is enough space - but I'm not sure enough to post this as an answer. Source: IIRC no one was asked to gate check bags during my last flight with a CRJ900 (Lufthansa Regional). However, the plane was half empty, so overall space was not an issue. Also, I don't know about LGA, but in FRA these small planes are always assigned tarmac positions and "big" hand luggage is handed over right next to the airplane - there is hardly any wait (at least not for those sitting in the back, and the bus won't leave until everyone got off the plane and on the bus :) )

Comment: Would it not be simpler to ask the airline? In my limited experience airlines which fly small planes have information on their web-sites about the size they accept.

Answer (score 4):

It will vary a bit depending on the aircraft version, but in general, the overhead bins on the CRJ-700/705/900 series (I've flown on all three) are quite small and will not accept carry-on bags that would fit in the overhead bin of larger aircraft like A320/B737.

I would either take your smaller bag, or just check a bag and then you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: The CRJ900s used by Delta definitely do not have space for full sized carry-ons, my large "briefcase" just barely fits.

Comment: My older shoulder camera bag, which fits on bins on 737s, A320s, and even the Embraer 175/190, does *not* fit in the overhead bin of Air Canada's CRJ-705s.  I have to put it underneath the seat in front of me, and put my briefcase in the overhead bin.  (Luckily my new backpack bag fits in the overhead bin on the CRJs just fine.)